# -ms-transform-origin is not working on IE9

Tags: css, compass-sass

I am doing a radar animation usng transform and transform-origin. This is the following CSS I have. But it doesn't work on IE9.

```
@keyframes ring2 {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin:center center 0;
        -moz-transform-origin:center center 0;
        -ms-transform-origin:center center 0;
        transform-origin:center center 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:center center 0;
    -moz-transform-origin:center center 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:center center 0;
    transform-origin:center center 0;
 }
}
```

Is there a workaround to make it work on IE9? I though that if I used the prefix -ms it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At-rule `@keyframes` is part of CSS **Animations** module level 3 (*CSS3 Animations*) and was introduced in IE with **IE10**. So it doesn't work at all in lesser versions including IE9.

- [MDN @keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) with compatibility table
- [MSDN @keyframes (at-)rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [caniuse CSS3 Animation](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

Comment: Thank you. when I typed transform on caniuse it just tells me that I could add the prefix -ms and that's what I did without succeeding at it.

Answer (score 2):

The `-ms-transform-origin` only work with 2D transform. In other words, you supposed to use 2 properties, not 3.

The 3rd is the Z vector and transform3D doesn't work on IE9.

Try this and see if it work:

```css
@keyframes ring2 {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin:center center;
        -moz-transform-origin:center center;
        -ms-transform-origin:center center;
        transform-origin:center center;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:center center;
    -moz-transform-origin:center center;
    -ms-transform-origin:center center;
    transform-origin:center center;
 }
}
```